# Updating vote counter rails ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails app, in which my Posts model has Comments and the comments are votable. I'm using acts_as_votable.

I currently have the voting on the comments working. Now I'm trying to implement some javascript so that the page does not have to refresh every time someone votes on a comment, so that the vote goes through.

This is what I have in my comments controller:

```
  def upvote_post_comment
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.liked_by current_user

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back }
    format.json { render json: { count: @comment.votes.size } }
   end
end
```

And this is what I have in my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user != comment.user && !(current_user.voted_for? comment) %>


    <%= link_to image_tag(‘vote.png'), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, class: 'vote', remote: true, data: { type: :json } %> 
<a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>

   <script>

    $('.vote')
  .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:error', function(e, xhr, status, error) { console.log(status); console.log(error); })
  .on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).html(data.count); });

    </script>


  <% elsif user_signed_in? && (current_user = comment.user) %>

  <%= image_tag(‘voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>


  <% else %>

  <%= image_tag(‘voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>


    <% end %>
```

**When I click on the vote.png icon, the icon disappears and the vote count shows up instead of it. How do I get the vote.png icon to change to the voted.png icon and the vote count to update within the designated placeholder?**

```
<a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>
```

The rendered HTML:

```
<p>

<p>comment test</p>

<a class="vote" data-method="put" data-remote="true" data-type="json" href="/1/comments/8/like" rel="nofollow">

<img src="/assets/vote.png" />
<span>0</span>

</a>


</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer:

You're updating your entire `.vote` element (including your image). You need to differentiate between `.vote img` and `.vote span`:

```
 <%= link_to like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, class: 'vote', remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %> 
     <%= image_tag(‘vote.png') %>
     <%= content_tag :span, comment.votes.size %>
 <% end %>

.on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).find('span').html(data.count); }
```

---

**Re-Factored Answer**

```
    #app/assets/javascripts/application.js
    $(document)
    .on('ajax:send', '.vote', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
    .on('ajax:complete', '.vote', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
    .on('ajax:error', '.vote', function(e, xhr, status, error) { console.log(status); console.log(error); })
    .on('ajax:success', '.vote', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).find("span").html(data.count); });

    #view
    <% if user_signed_in? && current_user != comment.user %>

     <% if !(current_user.voted_for? comment) %>

        <%= link_to like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, class: 'vote', remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %> 
            <%= image_tag('vote.png') %>
            <%= content_tag :span, comment.votes.size %>
        <% end %>

      <% else %>
         <%= image_tag('voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a> 
      <% end %>

   <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now it only shows the vote.png icon if the comment has not been voted for, the comments that have been voter for done have anything and when I click on the vote icon for the ones that do, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for comment - Can you be a little more precise? I think there is a syntax error in your provided code (which has translated over to mine), but if you could be more specific, it will be a big help!

Comment: So I only want to show the vote icon if the user is signed in and the comment does not belong to the current user and the current user has not already voted for the comment. For some reason the voted and vote icons are not displaying properly. Only the vote.png icon is displaying on some of the comments and the voted.png icon is not displaying anywhere. On the comments where the vote.png icon appears, when clicking it, I can see this within terminal: Processing by CommentsController#upvote_post_comment as JSON
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>”1”, "id"=>"5"}, but nothing actually happens in the view.

Comment: The vote count does not change and the icon does not change, even after refreshing the page.

Comment: I think the controller code is working fine, because it looks like the request actually goes through. Could it be some caching issue?

Comment: Can you post your rendered HTML in your question please Katie? I'll be in a better position to help you then!

Comment: Yup, this is what is rendered per comment!

Comment: Do you have time to continue this in the chat box thing?

Comment: Hi Kate, I am back - let's go into chat if you want

Comment: That would be great! How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing your vote.png on your on success call.

```
.on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).html(data.count); });
```

Replace "this" with the class of your comment.votes.size.